# Is SharePoint List is equivalent to lotus Forms?

Tags: sharepoint, lotus-notes

After some reading and R&D, I have came to conclusion that ?

- Forms in lotus notes = List in sharepoint.
- And Fields in Lotus Forms = Column in Sharepoint List.

But in some articals I found Lotus View is List in Sharepoint.so I am confused ,

So need experts advice

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Forms in Lotus Notes are a GUI-based way to edit and get data into the back-end documents.  Lotus Notes stores data in document objects, which are essentially unstructured records (meaning they have no schema or requirements on what fields exist within).  Through forms, developers can set required fields and maintain control over how data gets into each document, but technically Notes agents and scripts could alter those documents without adhering to any rules about the data contained within.

Notes views are visualizations of the Notes documents, allowing you to filter the documents and display columns of data they contain.

SharePoint Lists are structured and you must create a schema defining what data is allowed in each field of the list record.  The views used to display the list data are similar to Notes views in some ways, but nothing is really exactly the same between the two systems.

To tie the two into common database concepts of Table > Record > Column, here's how the two systems work in those terms:

**Lotus Notes:**

Table = Notes Form.  You can think of a Notes Form as the table since typically it has the most influence over the schema for your data, although as I said Notes documents (i.e. records) are unstructured and can hold any data.

Record = Notes Document.  The document is the data container behind the scenes.  When you click on an email in Lotus Notes, you're selecting a back-end document.  When you open that email, you're displaying that document in a Notes Form, the Mail form.

Column = Notes Item.  A Notes document is made up of many items.  Not to be confused with the concept of a column in Lotus Notes Views, which is for display purposes only.

**SharePoint:**

Table = List.  The list settings define what data is stored in the list.

Record = List item.  The list is made up of individual items, just like records in a database table.

Column = Column.  For the purposes of this explanation, these are the same.

Comment: If I had found this comment when I first had to learn Lotus Domino designer I could have saved so much time. Excellently written.